# How to auto submit a Rails form on a page visit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

i have a form which i want to be auto submited when a page is visited maybe through jquery or any other means the reason why is that i want a create action to be triggered so i can make use it my table for the form is

```
class CreateWhatsups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :whatsups do |t|
      t.string :details, :default => "visited"
      t.integer :user_id


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

my form includes

```
<%= form_for(@whatsup) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :details %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :details %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

how do i make this form auto submit when i place it anywhere in my rails application without clicking the submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the document.ready event of JQuery
For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("formname").submit();
});
```

Comment: the $("formname") is it a class or an id of the form ?

Comment: @IbrahimSediqAbubakar That's up to you. you can use whatever you want: `$("#this_is_an_id")` and `$(".this_is_a_class")`. You use `#` in front of an id and `.` in front of a class.

Comment: thanks a lot it works pretty well thanks alot  .... one more thing is i want a after the form is auto submitted, i should not be redirected but to stay on that same page

Answer (score 1):

To send the form and stay on the same page, you need to send an ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: $('#formid').attr('action'),
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('failure');
      }
    });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/f6M4k/)

I hope this helps ;)